# Deep NN for multivariate regression

Tags: r, machine-learning

I implemented this simple NN but even when making it do all the interactions it fails to converge and the MSE remains very high

I tried to change the number of iterations and the learning rate but it doesn't work

```
rm(list=ls())
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Mikele/Documents/Uni/IA AI & Machine Learning/R/11_23_2018/wine.csv",sep = ',',header = FALSE)

x <- data[,1:11]
y <- as.matrix(data[,12])

y_matrix <- matrix(rep(0,length(y)),nrow = length(y), ncol = 6)
k <-1

for (w in 1:length(y)) 
{
  temp <- y[k] - 2
  y_matrix[k,temp] <-1
  k <- k + 1
}

hl <- c(40, 30, 20)
iter <- 1000
lr <- 0.1

## add in intercept
x_1 <- as.matrix(cbind(rep(1, nrow(x)),x))

## set error array
error <- rep(0, iter)

## set up weights
## the +1 is to add in the intercept/bias parameter
W1 <- matrix(runif(ncol(x_1)*hl[1], -1, 1), nrow = ncol(x_1))
W2 <- matrix(runif((hl[1]+1)*hl[2], -1, 1), nrow = hl[1]+1)
W3 <- matrix(runif((hl[2]+1)*hl[3], -1, 1), nrow = hl[2]+1)
W4 <- matrix(runif((hl[3]+1)*ncol(y), -1, 1), nrow = hl[3]+1)

for(k in 1:iter)
{
  # calculate the hidden and output layers using X and hidden layer as inputs
  # hidden layer 1 and 2 have a column of ones appended for the bias term
  hidden1 <- cbind(matrix(1, nrow = nrow(x_1)), sigm(x_1 %*% W1))
  hidden2 <- cbind(matrix(1, nrow = nrow(x_1)), sigm(hidden1 %*% W2))
  hidden3 <- cbind(matrix(1, nrow = nrow(x_1)), sigm(hidden2 %*% W3))
  y_hat <- sigm(hidden3 %*% W4)

  # calculate the gradient and back prop the errors
  # see theory above
  y_hat_del <- (y-y_hat)*(d.sigm(y_hat))
  hidden3_del <- y_hat_del %*% t(W4)*d.sigm(hidden3)
  hidden2_del <- hidden3_del[,-1] %*% t(W3)*d.sigm(hidden2)
  hidden1_del <- hidden2_del[,-1] %*% t(W2)*d.sigm(hidden1)

  # update the weights
  W4 <- W4 + lr*t(hidden3) %*% y_hat_del
  W3 <- W3 + lr*t(hidden2) %*% hidden3_del[,-1]
  W2 <- W2 + lr*t(hidden1) %*% hidden2_del[,-1]
  W1 <- W1 + lr*t(x_1) %*% hidden1_del[,-1]

  error[k] <- 1/nrow(y)*sum((y-y_hat)^2)
  if((k %% (10^4+1)) == 0) cat("mse:", error[k], "\n")      
}

# plot loss
xvals <- seq(1, iter, length = 100)
print(qplot(xvals, error[xvals], geom = "line", main = "MSE", xlab = "Iteration"))
```

no error message but I can't understand how to make a deep NN for 
Multivariate Linear Regression 
in addition I divided the ys into a 6-column matrix (the maximum and minimum of the initial dataset) now there is someone who can help me understand why not cover and in any case the final results are all concentrated on column 4?

Comment: Sorry Michele, what is the problem with the code? and what is your question?

Comment: For this code I have taken inspiration from another example where the outputs y are between 0 and 1 instead what I would like are values ​​from 1 to 10. and I would like someone to help me understand how, since this is the basic structure for the deep NN, get these outputs